# Should debug and debugging tags be synonyms? Should they be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Should debug and debugging tags be synonyms? Should they be merged? I think so. I would like to hear your opinion.

I am referring to [debug tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debug?sort=votes&pageSize=15) and [debugging tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging?sort=votes&pageSize=15).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging is generally the more used term. "To debug" is the infinitive. That's a tad too Shatner even for me. Boldly merged, it is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!